# How to make deeply nested function call polymorphic?

Tags: oop, functional-programming, refactoring

So I have a custom programming language, and in it I am doing some math formalization/modeling. In this instance I am doing basically this (a pseudo-javascript representation):

```
isIntersection([1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [2, 3]) // => true
isIntersection([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]) // => false

function isIntersection(setTest, setA, setB) {
  i = 0
  while (i < setTest.length) {
    let t = setTest[i]
    if (includes(setA, t) || includes(setB, t)) {
      i++
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
}

function includes(set, element) {
  for (x in set) {
    if (isEqual(element, x)) {
      return true
    }
  }
  return false
}

function isEqual(a, b) {
  if (a is Set && b is Set) {
    return isSetEqual(a, b)
  } else if (a is X... && b is X...) {
    return isX...Equal(a, b)
  } ... {
    ...
  }
}

function isSetEqual(a, b) {
  i = 0
  while (i < a.length) {
    let x = a[i]
    let y = b[i]
    if (!isEqual(x, y)) {
      return false
    }
    i++
  }
  return true
}
```

The `isIntersection` is checking `isEqual`, and `isEqual` is configured to be able to handle all kinds of cases of equality check, from sets compared to sets, objects to objects, X's to X's, etc..

The question is, how can we make the `isEqual` somehow ignorant of the implementation details? Right now you have to have one big if/else/switch statement for every possible type of object. If we add a new type, we have to modify this gigantic `isEqual` method to add support for it. How can we avoid this, and just define them separately and cleanly?

I was thinking initially of making the objects be "instances of classes" so to speak, with class methods. But I like the purity of having everything just be functions and structs (objects without methods). Is there any way to implement this sort of thing without using classes with methods, instead keeping it just functions and objects?

If not, then how would you implement it with classes? Would it just be something like this?

```
class Set {
  isEqual(set) {
    i = 0
    while (i < this.length) {
      let x = this[i]
      let y = set[i]
      if (!x.isEqual(y)) {
        return false
      }
      i++
    }
    return true
  }
}
```

This would mean every object would have to have an `isEqual` defined on it. How does Haskell handle such a system? Basically looking for inspiration on how this can be most cleanly done. I want to ideally avoid having classes with methods.

*Note: You can't just delegate to `==` native implementation (like assuming this is in JavaScript). We are using a custom programming language and are basically trying to define the meaning of `==` in the first place.*

Another approach is to pass around an `isEqual` function along with everything somehow, though I don't really see how to do this and if it were possible it would be clunky. So not sure what the best approach is.

Comment: In Haskell you have parametricity, i.e. you have to treat every type uniformly. Although parametricity comes along with nice properties it restricts what you can do with a type, because you have no knowledge about it. Type classes are a means to give you some knowledge about a type or how it acts in certain aspects. Equality forms such a type class. I am neither a type theorist nor well-versed in Haskell, but I think of type classes as first class name overloadings at the type level. This is all very specific to the Hindley-Milner type system, though and probably won't help you much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haskell leverages its type and type-class system to deal with polymorphic equality.

The relevant code is

```hs
class Eq a where
   (==) :: a -> a -> Bool
```

The English translation is: a type `a` implements the `Eq` class if, and only if, it defines a function `(==)` which takes two inputs of type `a` and outputs a `Bool`.

Generally, we declare certain "laws" that type-classes should abide by. For example, `x == y` should be identical to `y == x` in all cases, and `x == x` should never be `False`. There's no way for the compiler to check these laws, so one typically just writes them into the documentation.

Once we have defined the typeclass `Eq` in the above manner, we have access to the `(==)` function (which can be called using infix notation - ie, we can either write `(==) x y` or `x == y`). The type of this function is

```hs
(==) :: forall a . Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
```

In other words, for every `a` that implements the typeclass `Eq`, `(==)` is of type `a -> a -> Bool`.

Consider an example type

```hs
data Boring = Dull | Uninteresting
```

The type `Boring` has two proper values, `Dull` and `Uninteresting`. We can define the `Eq` implementation as follows:

```hs
instance Eq Boring where
   Dull == Dull                   = True
   Dull == Uninteresting          = False
   Uninteresting == Uninteresting = True
   Uninteresting == Dull          = False
```

Now, we will be able to evaluate whether two elements of type `Boring` are equal.

```
ghci> Dull == Dull
True
ghci> Dull == Uninteresting
False
```

Note that this is very different from Javascript's notion of equality. It's not possible to compare elements of different types using `(==)`. For example,

```
ghci> Dull == 'w'
<interactive>:146:9: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Boring' with actual type `Char'
    * In the second argument of `(==)', namely 'w'
      In the expression: Dull == 'w'
      In an equation for `it': it = Dull == 'w'
```

When we try to compare `Dull` to the character `'w'`, we get a type error because `Boring` and `Char` are different types.

We can thus define

```hs
includes :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> Bool
includes [] _           = False
includes (x:xs) element = element == x || includes xs element
```

We read this definition as follows:

`includes` is a function that, for any type `a` which implements equality testing, takes a list of `a`s and a single `a` and checks whether the element is in the list.

If the list is empty, then `includes list element` will evaluate to `False`.

If the list is not empty, we write the list as `x : xs` (a list with the first element as `x` and the remaining elements as `xs`). Then `x:xs` includes `element` iff either `x` equals `element`, or `xs` includes `element`.

We can also define

```hs
instance Eq a => Eq [a] where
   []     == []     = True
   []     == (_:_)  = False
   (_:_)  == []     = False
   (x:xs) == (y:ys) = x == y && xs == ys
```

The English translation of this code is:

Consider any type `a` such that `a` implements the `Eq` class (in other words, so that `(==)` is defined for type `a`). Then `[a]` also implements the `Eq` type class - that is, we can use `(==)` on two values of type `[a]`.

The way that `[a]` implements the typeclass is as follows:

The empty list equals itself.

An empty list does not equal a non-empty list.

To decide whether two non-empty lists `(x:xs)` and `(y:ys)` are equal, check whether their first elements are equal (aka whether `x == y`). If the first elements are equal, check whether the remaining elements are equal (whether `xs == ys`) recursively. If both of these are true, the two lists are equal. Otherwise, they're not equal.

Notice that we're actually using two different `==`s in the implementation of `Eq [a]`. The equality `x == y` is using the `Eq a` instance, while the equality `xs == ys` is recursively using the `Eq [a]` instance.

In practice, defining `Eq` instances is typically so simple that Haskell lets the compiler do the work. For example, if we had instead written

```hs
data Boring = Dull | Uninteresting deriving (Eq)
```

Haskell would have automatically generated the `Eq Boring` instance for us. Haskell also lets us derive other type classes like `Ord` (where the functions `(<)` and `(>)` are defined), `show` (which allows us to turn our data into `String`s), and `read` (which allows us to turn `String`s back into our data type).

Keep in mind that this approach relies heavily on static types and type-checking. Haskell makes sure that we only ever use the `(==)` function when comparing elements of the same type. The compiler also always knows at compile type which definition of `(==)` to use in any given situation because it knows the types of the values being compared, so there is no need to do any sort of dynamic dispatch (although there are situations where the compiler will choose to do dynamic dispatch).

If your language uses dynamic typing, this method will not work and you'll be forced to use dynamic dispatch of some variety if you want to be able to define new types. If you use static typing, you should definitely look into Haskell's type class system.